# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I have a project in WordPress. I am trying to implement dialog box popup  on click of hyperlink.

On click of this link, function `shownm1()` is called which is placed in `.js` file. The function contains code to open modal dialog.

But its showing the following error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog' .

```
<a href="#" id="test-div1" onclick="shownm1()">Click</a>

function shownm1(){  
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
//                    alert(1);
    $('#test-div1' ).dialog( "open" );

});
}
```

I suppose the scripts for dialog popup are not loading. Can anyone suggest how to enqueue scripts for the same? Or is there any other problem?

Comment: `dialog()` doesn't seem to be jQuery method, where do you expect it to come from?

Comment: How should i get it working? I have no idea how to use these scripts <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> to enable dialog function in wordpress theme

Comment: i have this function in my functions.php file        function load_all_jquery(){
    wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-core");
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog');
wp_enqueue_style("wp-jquery-ui-dialog");
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_all_jquery' );

Comment: [Edit] those comments into the question. Code formatting in comments is minimal at best making code all but impossible to read. I would also suggest you search this site for `wp_enqueue_script`.

Comment: I got it working by placing following code in my functions.php file   function custom_scripts3() { 
    wp_register_script(   'myhandle5','//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js' , 'jquery', '1.0',  false );
//                                       wp_register_style( 'myhandle6', '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'myhandle5' );                                        wp_enqueue_style( 'myhandle6' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts3' );